# Error: initializer element is not computable at load time

Tags: c, gcc, ansi-c, gcc-pedantic

I have a function that takes a struct, and I'm trying to store its variables in array:

```
int detect_prm(Param prm) {
  int prm_arr[] = {prm.field1, prm.field2, prm.field3};

  return 0;
}
```

But with `gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic-errors -Werror` I get the following error:

> initializer element is not computable at load time

It looks fine to me, what's wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is illegal in C. Initializer lists must be constant compile time expressions. Do the following instead:

```
int prm_arr[3];

prm_arr[0] = prm.field1;
prm_arr[1] = prm.field2;
prm_arr[2] = prm.field3;
```

Comment: Illegal in C89 which is the standard implied by -ansi; legal in C99, which can be enabled by using -std=c99 instead of -ansi.

Answer (score 18):

Mike's answer is absolutely right.

However, if you're able to use the GNU C extensions, or to use the newer and better C99 standard instead (use the `--std=c99` option), then initializers such as this are perfectly legal.  The C99 standard has been out for, well, 9 years, and most C compilers support it quite well... especially this feature.

Comment: Just FYI, Visual Studio 2008 (which officially supports only C89) emits the following warning at `/W4` : `warning C4221: nonstandard extension used : 'nxstate' : cannot be initialized using address of automatic variable 'x'`. The generated assembly looks alright, though, so I'd say you can rely on this feature even in MSVC.

Comment: Visual Studio did not officially support [C99 until 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx). Only 14 years late. *bangs head*

Comment: that calls for a party!