# C: Is this type of initialization correct?

Tags: c

```
int startingPoint[2]={i,j};
```

I got this after reading an online code.Is this correct? Means if values of i and j can be changed at runtime before this statement, will this initialize the array with the correct values? Please explain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works in C99 but not in C89.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160960/error-initializer-element-is-not-computable-at-load-time .

Answer (score 1):

> int startingPoint[2]={i,j};
>   I got this after reading an online code.Is this correct?

Yes that is a correct C code(will work on all modern C compilers).However that wont work on a C89 compiler.

> Means if values of i and j can be changed at runtime before this statement, will this initialize the array with the correct values?

Yes!

```
scanf("%d %d",i,j);
/* some code */

int abc[]={i,j};
```