# Does C allows non-const expressions in array initializer list?

Tags: c

In the following code `a` array is initialized with `s` "seed" variable, which is clearly not constant expression (as it's evaluated "run-time"):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int s = 1, i;
    int a[] = {s, s + 2, s + 4, s + 6, s + 8};

    for (i = 0; i < (int) (sizeof a / sizeof a[0]); i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]); /* prints: 1 3 5 7 9  */
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles in `gcc -Wall -Wextra` with no warnings. However adding `-pedantic` provokes:

```
check.c: In function ‘main’:
check.c:8: warning: initializer element is not computable at load time
check.c:8: warning: initializer element is not computable at load time
check.c:8: warning: initializer element is not computable at load time
check.c:8: warning: initializer element is not computable at load time
check.c:8: warning: initializer element is not computable at load time
```

Does C require constant expression for initializer elements ?

Comment: no, since C99. try add `-std=c99`

Comment: Duplicate of [Error: initializer element is not computable at load time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160960/error-initializer-element-is-not-computable-at-load-time)

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thanks, I didn't notice it's already answered, maybe I should remove this question as not useful.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski not really. The posted answer is additionally helpful due to the standard citation. I'd keep it and mark it done if it helped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is valid in c99 but not valid in c89 (emphasize mine):

> (C89, 6.5.7) "All the expression in an initializer for an object       that has static storage duration **or in an initializer list for an             object that has aggregate or union** type shall be constant expressions"

but

> (C99, 6.7.8p4) "All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals."

By default, `gcc` compiles with `-std=gnu89` which is c89 + GNU extensions.

Comment: Is `s+2` a constant expression in C99?

Comment: +1 stressing the **static storage duration**. Const expressions are required for globals, local `static`, etc.; automatics get a pass in C99.

Comment: @sharth `s + 2` is not a constant expression but an array initializer has to be a constant expression in c89. In c99 if the array is not static, the initializers are not required to be constant expressions.

Comment: @ouah: Yeah. I thought `s+2` wasn't a constant expression, but I missed the bit about static. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ouah's excellent answer I would add that C99 requires constant expression for *`designators`* within *`designated initializers`* (only in C99), e.g. following array initialization is invalid in C99:

```
int s = 1, i = 0;
int a[] = {[i] = s, [i+1] = s + 2, [i+2] = s + 4, s + 6, s + 8};
```

which might be rewritten as e.g.:

```
#define I 0

int s = 1, i;
int a[] = {[I] = s, [I+1] = s + 2, [I+2] = s + 4, s + 6, s + 8};
```